# Optimizing a MySQL query that finds duplicate data

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query that I use for finding duplicate data. I have found that lately the query is very slow, and only getting slower. This is the query I am using (columns renamed):

```
  SELECT col1, 
         COUNT(col1) AS Counter 
    FROM people 
GROUP BY col1 
  HAVING (Counter > 1)
```

I have indexed col1 (which is a varchar(500)), but the query takes an epic amount of time to execute. Is there a better way to handle this, or am I stuck?

Comment: Is duplicate data allowed per your business rules?  Otherwise, I'd clean out the duplicates, and put a unique (if not primary) key on the column(s) to stop the data from getting into the table in the first place.

Comment: Duplicates are allowed, but only when certain other conditions are present. It's a bit murky, but it's something I need to work around. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    people po
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    people pi
        WHERE   pi.col1 = po.col1
        LIMIT 1, 1
        )
```

This will return you each duplicated instance.

Comment: Just to let you know, the query went from 90 seconds down to 4 seconds with this change. Thanks!